# Blazor WASM: Detailed Error on Production Environment

Tags: debugging, iis, blazor, webassembly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

> Detailed errors during development When a Blazor app isn't functioning
> properly during development, receiving detailed error information from
> the app assists in troubleshooting and fixing the issue. When an error
> occurs, Blazor apps display a light yellow bar at the bottom of the
> screen: During development, the bar directs you to the browser
> console, where you can see the exception. In production, the bar
> notifies the user that an error has occurred and recommends refreshing
> the browser.

The information on this page is pretty clear. However, I still need to capture detailed error messages on my prod system using pdb files. In previous classical applications, I could provide this via web.config.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
```

When I debugging in the development environment, I can get the stack trace (file name and line number) information of the error. I'm publishing my Blazor WASM project with the "DEBUG" configuration profile. However, I still am not getting the detailed error messages.

Setting "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development" also did not work.

I can understand the basic safety concerns. However, I still think that there should be an opportunity to express a preference in this matter. Is there a point I'm missing? Or is Blazor WASM blocking this by default in prod environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thanks your comment. This behavior is not specific to IIS. It behaves the same when self-hosting dotnet with the server.exe file.